# Why assign export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:

Tags: bash, shell, kernel

I know

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=xxxxx
```

will let kernel to search target lib in this path.

but why assign it as **':'**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:
```

What's the function? It works if .so in the current path.

By the way, when we separate paths, shouldn't we use ';' ?

ex:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foo1;foo2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used by the dynamic linker not the kernel. The name of the dynamic linker varies but is something like /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2.

It is documented by `man ld.so`. On my system it says

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
          A list of directories in which to search for ELF libraries at execution
          time.  The items in the list are separated by either colons or
          semicolons, and there is no support for escaping either separator.
```

Using colon has the minor advantage of not needing quotes, as `;` is a special character to the shell. It also agrees with the use of colon in the value of the PATH variable.

As to why `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:`, I suggest getting a better book or guide.

Comment: When I doing: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:    this works to find my lib in current path, why?

Comment: You are adding two directories, each with the name of the empty string, to the places to search, one each side of the colon. By a quirk an empty string is taken to be the same as ".", the current directory. It would be more efficient to say LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.